# The style of plot line changes if \addplot+ order changes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles, pgfplotstable

I have a weird issue with this simple plot. I need to draw four couples of plots, each made by an approximate curve (continuous line) and the real curve (dashed line). For some reasons I can't understand the plot (t,y_p20a) is dashed, but it shouldn't be. Another weird thing is that if I rearrange the plot couples in a different order, such as 12 34 78 56, the issue is still on the seventh plot (which is, in this case, the number 5). Any idea?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
t,y_m20r,y_m10r,y_p10r,y_p20r,y_m20a,y_m10a,y_p10a,y_p20a
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0.022341,0.0099981,-0.0082633,-0.015207,0.018097,0.0090484,-0.0090484,-0.018097
2,0.03993,0.017993,-0.015022,-0.027751,0.032749,0.016375,-0.016375,-0.032749
3,0.053529,0.024287,-0.020482,-0.037983,0.044449,0.022225,-0.022225,-0.044449
4,0.063789,0.02914,-0.024824,-0.046211,0.053626,0.026813,-0.026813,-0.053626
5,0.071269,0.032777,-0.028206,-0.05271,0.060653,0.030327,-0.030327,-0.060653
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{data.csv}\data

\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}

  \addplot table[x = t, y = y_m20a] from \data;
  \addplot [dashed] table[x = t, y = y_m20r] from \data;

  \addplot table[x = t, y = y_m10a] from \data;
  \addplot [dashed] table[x = t, y = y_m10r] from \data;

  \addplot table[x = t, y = y_p10a] from \data;
  \addplot [dashed] table[x = t, y = y_p10r] from \data;

  \addplot table[x = t, y = y_p20a] from \data; % THIS ONE SHOULD NOT BE DASHED
  \addplot [dashed] table[x = t, y = y_p20r] from \data;

\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all determined by the so-called `cycle list`. If you change it, you get rid of the dashes. Here is an example.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
t,y_m20r,y_m10r,y_p10r,y_p20r,y_m20a,y_m10a,y_p10a,y_p20a
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0.022341,0.0099981,-0.0082633,-0.015207,0.018097,0.0090484,-0.0090484,-0.018097
2,0.03993,0.017993,-0.015022,-0.027751,0.032749,0.016375,-0.016375,-0.032749
3,0.053529,0.024287,-0.020482,-0.037983,0.044449,0.022225,-0.022225,-0.044449
4,0.063789,0.02914,-0.024824,-0.046211,0.053626,0.026813,-0.026813,-0.053626
5,0.071269,0.032777,-0.028206,-0.05271,0.060653,0.030327,-0.030327,-0.060653
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{data.csv}\data
\pgfplotsset{
    cycle list={
        {mark=*},
        {mark=*},
        {mark=diamond*},
        {mark=triangle*},  {blue,mark=triangle*},
        {red, mark=diamond*},   {blue,mark=diamond*},
        {red, mark=pentagon*},  {blue,mark=pentagon*}
    }}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

  \addplot table[x = t, y = y_m20a] from \data;
  \addplot [dashed] table[x = t, y = y_m20r] from \data;

  \addplot table[x = t, y = y_m10a] from \data;
  \addplot [dashed] table[x = t, y = y_m10r] from \data;

  \addplot table[x = t, y = y_p10a] from \data;
  \addplot [dashed] table[x = t, y = y_p10r] from \data;

  \addplot table[x = t, y = y_p20a] from \data; % THIS ONE SHOULD NOT BE DASHED
  \addplot [dashed] table[x = t, y = y_p20r] from \data;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to just ignore any cycle list? In my document (here I wrote just a MWE with no formatting) I added the options `no markers, thick` to the axis environment and I specified a color for each `\addplot+` command, so I don't need pgfplots to cycle within any formatting list, everything is manually specified for each plot. I tried to add the `solid` option to the axis environment, and I also tried with `every axis plot/.style`, with no success...

Comment: @Taekwondavide One quick way is to say `\pgfplotsset{cycle list={}}` and then set the marks, colors and line styles by hand, if needed. Or just make sure every plot has some options. The pgfplots manual says on p. 25 "Note furthermore that we omitted any options after \addplot. As explained in Section 3.2.1, this tells pgfplots to consult its cycle list to determine a suitable option list."

Comment: Thank you, now it works. However, is there any reason for which I can globally set `no markers` but I cannot set `solid`? The first overrides the cycle list, the second is just ignored...

Comment: I just tried this (as a tikzpicture option), it doesn't work. I think it's just for marks and not for the line, as I replaced `solid` with `yellow` and it changed the border color of marks.

Comment: @Taekwondavide Yes, you're right. I have no idea *why* it is seemingly impossible to override these things globally in the same way as other things. Nevertheless the things mentioned above seem to work.